# Current recommended installation for MacBook Pro? (OS X 10.9)

Tags: catkin, macbook, ros-hydro, gradle, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just bought a new Retina MacBook Pro which has OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) installed on it and I need to install ROS in the simplest way to continue developing. I am currently using ROSJava Groovy with the gradle build system on Ubuntu 13.04 (unsupported) and I am wondering which way is best to install ROS.

The options I'm currently considering are:

- Mac OS X 10.9 install with ROSJava Groovy
- Ubuntu 13.04 with ROSJava Groovy
- Some OS with Hydro

but any advice would be appreciated.

I would prefer to install on Mac OS X however I have previously tried to install it on OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) and could never manage to install it successfully.

I'm also reluctant to upgrade to the Catkin build system as I have been using Gradle and don't have experience of Catkin but I would upgrade if I couldn't avoid it.

Is anyone able to recommend the best install method for people in this situation?

Thanks for your help in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112421/current-recommended-installation-for-macbook-pro?-(os-x-10.9)/) by [heyfred](https://answers.ros.org/users/1930/heyfred/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2013-12-20

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you need to install ros in the simplest way, then I suggest getting a virtual machine and install ubuntu on it and install ros in there. As for OSX, it is definitely possible, but count on it to take some time and some searching through the web for solutions to compile errors and such when building ROS.

If you do want to go through with it, this'd be a good place to start:

http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2013-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2013-12-21**:
I fully agree that ubuntu will be the easiest. I have recently installed hydro on my Mavericks machine on OSX. The desktop-full install works, but there a few manual fixing steps involved (I'm happy to offer assistance here on ros answers). I don't know about ROSJava though.

**Comment by [jensenb](https://answers.ros.org/users/4449/jensenb/) on 2013-12-21**:
I also agree with Hansg91. While most of the issues with hydro on OS X have been resolved, not all have been released (so you will still need to patch the packages by hand), and some packages like Orocos KDL have no immediate solution in sight.

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-12-22**:
We have a good OS X community here :) Just my two cents, there're still some unresolved issues on OSX. http://answers.ros.org/question/64346/rviz-does-not-display-image-invalid-drawable-on-mac-osx-1083/  But I should admit that ROS is definitely usable! Let us know how ROSJava is working on OSX.

**Comment by [heyfred](https://answers.ros.org/users/1930/heyfred/) on 2013-12-30**:
I have decided to install ros groovy in a Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine which was an easy installation. I haven't tried connecting it to a robot yet but all of the drivers have installed fine. Thanks for the answers.